# Can’t use https://vintage.myetherwallet.com properly from WebKit

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

Why I can’t use https://vintage.myetherwallet.com properly from the WebKit. The problem is that when you open it in WebKit and go to the menu “Send Ether & Tokens” > Private key it’s not opening the textfield to type the private key, but when you open it from Safari it works. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SFSafariViewController`

It works with the following code :

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if let url = URL(string: "https://vintage.myetherwallet.com/") {
            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            vc.delegate = self
            self.present(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```