# Why is WkWebView not playing in line?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am developing an `iOS` application and for some reason the videos (which are embed in a page of the website) do not `playinline`. I have to mention that on `iPhone's safari`, the videos play in line. It does not open fullscreen. Only on `WkWebView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a SFSafariViewController.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if let url = URL(string: "https://example.com") {
            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            vc.delegate = self
            self.present(vc, animated: true) {
                // Include this code below to 'hide' the toolbar.
                var frame = vc.view.frame
                // If you want it to go under the safe area header bar:
                let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
                let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top
                let OffsetY: CGFloat  = 64 + topPadding
                frame.origin = CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y - OffsetY)
                frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height + OffsetY)

                safariViewController.view.frame = frame
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From a tangential [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368654/can-t-use-https-vintage-myetherwallet-com-properly-from-webkit) about struggling with the browser rendering properly with WKWebView, but working fine in Safari.

**EDIT:** Included code to hide the toolbar.

Comment: Hello. Yes, it works like that, but is there a way i can hide the safari type header and footer? The back buttons, and the header, where it appears the link and an "OK" button?

Comment: Hello. yes it does. Could you help me with one more thing? When i'm scrolling down, the content of the application is not stopping where the header of the phone is ( area that shows what time is it, the battery % and so on). It's displaying the content under the header. Do you know a fix for that?

Comment: Yeah, you can just grab the window's `safeAreaInsets.top` and add that to the `yOffset`. Added in the code above. Also, not sure why your edit was rejected - it was correct.